# CSS-LESS Animation doesn't work

Tags: css, less

I have a problem with my script. I have a section for avatar - image - and for this image on hover I want to change the color of the border. I can't find the problem, but it doesn't work.

```
          img{
             margin-right:15px;
             float: left;
             width:68px;
             height: 68px;
            .bdr(40px);
             border:5px solid #eeeeee;
          }
          img:hover{
             -webkit-animation: avatarAnimation 1s;
             -moz-animation: avatarAnimation 1s;
             -o-animation: avatarAnimation 1s;
             animation: avatarAnimation 1s;

            }
          @keyframes avatarAnimation {
            25% {
                background: red;
            }
            50% {
                border-color:#f27935;
            }
            75% {
                border-color:#1fbba6;
            }

          }
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. It works fine when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/HkSkg/

Comment: it doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: Chrome need the webkit prefix for keyframes - http://jsfiddle.net/HkSkg/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `-webkit-keyframes` for Chrome support.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Less, you can deal with different platforms using a mixin:

```
.make-keyframes(@name) {
  @keyframes @name {
    // content
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes @name {
    // content
  }
}
```

Here's an example using another mixin to generate your content (with the properties for each step in a variable):

```
// the properties to use in each step
@properties: ~'background: red', ~'border-color:#f27935', ~'border-color:#1fbba6';

// a mixin to create each step (@step is the step size in %)
.make-keyframe(@step, @count) when (@count > 0) {
  .make-keyframe(@step, (@count - 1) );
  @pos: @step * (@count);
  @{pos} {top: extract(@properties, @count);}
}

.make-keyframes(@name) {
  @keyframes @name {
    .make-keyframe(25%, length(@properties));
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes @name {
    .make-keyframe(25%, length(@properties));
  }
}

.make-keyframes(avatarAnimation);
```

This will generate the following CSS code:

```
@keyframes avatarAnimation {
  25% {
    top: background: red;
  }
  50% {
    top: border-color:#f27935;
  }
  75% {
    top: border-color:#1fbba6;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes avatarAnimation {
  25% {
    top: background: red;
  }
  50% {
    top: border-color:#f27935;
  }
  75% {
    top: border-color:#1fbba6;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Less version 2 you can use the autoprefix postprocessor plugin and the consensus is that you should use it for best practice.

When using the autoprefix plugin, you Less code should look like that below (save into `file.less`):

```
img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  border: 5px solid #eeeeee;
  &:hover {
    animation: avatarAnimation 1s;
  }
}

@keyframes avatarAnimation {
  25% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #f27935;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: #1fbba6;
  }
}
```

I have left out the `.bdr(40px);` call in the above.
Than you could compile the above with `lessc --autoprefix file.less` which will output as follows:

```
img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  border: 5px solid #eeeeee;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-animation: avatarAnimation 1s;
          animation: avatarAnimation 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes avatarAnimation {
  25% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #f27935;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: #1fbba6;
  }
}
@keyframes avatarAnimation {
  25% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #f27935;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: #1fbba6;
  }
}
```

You can also [specify the browsers](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers) you want to target in your project, for instance: `lessc --autoprefix="> 1%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, Opera 12.1" file.less`